# How to clean up HTML leaving only <a> <b> <i> <p> tags?

Tags: html, regex, text

I have to process a very large amount of HTML text for epub conversion, and every "automated" solution I found and tried is way less than satisfactory.

So I was thinking toward a regex batch command solution, but I am too regex illiterate to make it work, especially considering possible nesting instances. Can anybody help or point me to a surefire solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use regex. Pick a programming language. Find an HTML aware library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Use [the php strip_tags function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Look at the example, it will only capture the HTML tags, rest data will be skipped.
https://regex101.com/r/mr1ry0/1
Regex: `<.*?>`
But this will also include the closing tags too.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an HTML parser.
For simple cases you may try the following regex: `<[abip]>[^<>]*<\/[abip]>|<[abip][^<>]*\/>`

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't clean up things such as, for example, <p align="justify"> that should turn into <p>

Comment: @Marta, one more try - how about the following one: `<[abip][^>]*>[^<>]*<\/[abip]>|<[abip][^<>]*\/>`